# Unable to compile with win sdk 7.1 in visual studio express

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This specific project requires me to use the win sdk 7.1 tool set to compile, and I'm currently using vs express 2012. I am unable to compile anything if select Windows7.1SDK as the Platform Toolset, even a hello world program. The error I receive from the compiler is:

```
Error   1   error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets   57  5   ConsoleApplication1
```

The specific line contains:

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' == 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
```

Googling was no help, and I have reinstalled the sdk multiple times, as well as reinstalling visual studio express to use vs express 2013.

Comment: Also having this problem. Did you find any solution?